# How to get folder ids

Tags: android, android-image, special-folders

I am searching through the folders inside the DCIM folder on the android device

how do I get the folder id's that they are in ?

for example, if I have Camera folder, Picasa folder and other folders

I need this folder's ID

how do I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the `File` class from `java.lang.Object` to do this?

If so, you can get the file's name using `getName()` and the absolute path using `getAbsolutePath()`.

For more info, check out http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/example-of-file-explorer-in-android.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: no, i am using content resolver - and the files are kept in the internal android database, i wanted to get the row id of the indicated folder